# Passing a large amount of data to an aspx site and getting back a image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, postback

I am new to ASP.net programming and web programming in general so I don't know all the terms but I will try my best to get the point across.

I am writing a image generator that will take in a string and output a PNG. I have been able to successfully do this using the syntax `LabelGenerator.aspx?epl2=UrlEncodedMessageGoesHere` visiting that site will generate a PNG file that can be used right inside a web page for further display. However the issue is I may have a message that is over 2048 bytes and IIS does not like that.

I know doing a POST instead of a GET will free me from the 2048 limit, however I do not know how to pass that information along if I want to use the resultant image inside a IMG tag.

here is some code of how I am currently doing it.

```
public partial class LabelGenerator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    RotateFlipType RotateFlip;
    float Scale;
    String LabelCommands;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int rotateFlipInt;
            if (!float.TryParse(this.Request.QueryString["Scale"], out Scale))
                Scale = 1;
            if (!int.TryParse(this.Request.QueryString["RotateFlip"], out rotateFlipInt))
                rotateFlipInt = (int)RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
            RotateFlip = (RotateFlipType)rotateFlipInt;
            LabelCommands = this.Request.QueryString["epl2"];

            if (LabelCommands != null && LabelCommands.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var bitmap = GenerateLabel())
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("You did not enter a valid epl2 command");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("An error occurred during processing.");
        }

    }
    private Bitmap GenerateLabel()
    {
         //(snip)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the solutions Google used for their [Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html) to solve the same problem

> Specifying your chart as a URL in your browser or an  tag is called a GET request. Making a GET request is simple, but GET URLs are limited to 2K characters. What if you have more data than that?
>   Luckily, the Chart API supports HTTP POST for chart requests up to 16K long. The trade-off is the added complexity of using POST.

Basically they create a form on the page with hidden fields that contain the data to be sent. When posting this form, from within an `IFRAME`, the response is an image. Thier form looks something like this

```
<form action='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart' method='POST'>
  <input type="hidden" name="cht" value="lc"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="chtt" value="This is | my chart"  />
  <input type='hidden' name='chs' value='600x200' />
  <input type="hidden" name="chxt" value="x,y" />
  <input type='hidden' name='chd' value='t:40,20,50,20,100'/>
  <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

In this example the user need to click to submit button to get the image. In the [Google page](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/post_requests.html) there are further example of using javascript to trigger the POST

```
var frm = document.getElementById('post_form');
if (frm) { frm.submit(); }
```

Comment: The iframe solution is perfect for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick sample I hacked up that uses [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make an asynchronous post to retrieve the base64 encoded image. Not sure about the browser compatibility.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('Image.aspx', { Mood: "Happy" }, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] image;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    switch (Request.Form["Mood"])
    {
        case "Happy":
            image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("ImageHappy.png"));
            Response.Write("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(image) + "\" />");
            break;
        case "Sad":
            image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("ImageSad.png"));
            Response.Write("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(image) + "\" />");
            break;
    }
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in an img tag, I believe you have to first save it to disk/the server.  Then use the src attribute of the img tag to reference it with a web reference.

`<img src="images/image.png">` would work fine if you had a directory off the current directory named images.

Or

`<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/image.png">` if you want to specify an exact route to the image.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain is actually doing a good job on that side. Saving the bitmap directly to the stream avoids the need to save it to disk first

Comment: @Ron Harlev so what information does he want to pass to the img tag then?

Comment: What can I do to to get get around the 2k limit for the request for the image.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - Encrypt/Compress the string first, and then undo it in your code before processing it.

Comment: Also why cannot you use a form field like a textbox?